# I'm having problems with props and require in React Native

Tags: image, react-native, require

I  am trying to pass a string as foto to require on `<Image/>`, but I am receiving an error.

I can't fix it. I know it's just a dumb mistake, but I started to learn React Native this week.

```
Cerveja name="Brahma Garrafa 600ml" price= "6.00" foto = '../assets/images/brahma-garrafa.png'
source={require(**props.foto**)}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the documentation under the section ["Static Resources](http://reactnative.dev/docs/image.html#static-resources)":

> The only allowed way to refer to an image in the bundle is to
>   literally write require('image!name-of-the-asset') in the source.

So I suggest to add require to your props like this:

```
foto = require('../assets/images/brahma-garrafa.png');
```

then :

```
source={props.foto}
```

Comment: WARNING: Failed prop type: invalid prop 'source' supplied to 'image'. 
<Cerveja foto = "require('../assets/images/brahma-garrafa.png')"/>

Comment: @RodrigoPissinate can you share with us the entire code, please.

Comment: I have posted the code in as another  answer in the question. Please, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function cardapio(){
  return(
    <ScrollView>
    <Cerveja name="Cerveja lata" price= "6.00" photo = "require('../assets/images/brahma-garrafa.png')"/>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
function Cerveja(props) {
const [count,setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <View style={{flexDirection:"row", alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
      <View style={{flex: .3}}>
        <Image
          source={(props.photo)}
          resizeMode='contain'
        />
      </View>
```

There you go. I was have problem while pasting it.